# mongodb query opposite of value in range

Tags: mongodb

I have a mongoDB collection with data like this

```
{
    start: "5.3",
    end: "8.10",
    owner: "guy1"
} 

{
    start: "9.0",
    end: "14.5",
    owner: "guy2"
}
```

Suppose I wish to know who got element 6.2.
We can see that guy1 has got element 6.2 because he own element 5.3 to element 8.10.

This is opposite to

```
db.collection.find( { field: { $gt: value1, $lt: value2 } } );
```

**The fields specify the start and end. The supplied data is in between the range.**

Looking for the largest value of start which is smaller than the required value.

How to query this?

Answer (score 3):

Negating the logic, this should work:

```
db.collection.find( { start : { $lte : 6.2 }, end : { $gt : 6.2 } })
```

The problem is you need to ensure that you have no overlapping intervals, which can be tricky, but that is a problem at the application level. Also, please make sure you're not storing doubles as strings, otherwise the `$gt`/`$lt` queries will not work as expected, i.e make sure your data looks like this instead:

```
{
  start: 9.0,
  end: 14.5,
  owner: "guy2"
}
```

As pointed out by Michael, you should also make sure your interval logic works out, because there are different methods interval inclusion can be defined. Math notation is `)` vs. `]`, but the discussion gets more complicated with floating point numbers where there are limits on the value of a smallest epsilon which depends on the value of the number itself...

Comment: Well, or `$gte`, or even both - that depends on the interval logic... For example, does start/end being equal mean that that specific value is 'included' in the interval, or not? Mathematically speaking, a 1-dimensional sphere of radius 0 contains nothing, not even the point itself, but I guess that discussion is out of scope since the OP didn't provide much information on that question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can use [$not](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) operator (put your original query inside $not) or you knowing that

`not (x > a and x < b)` is equal to `x < a or x > b`

you can rewrite it with [$or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) query